# Drupal 7 - Blog Module - Categories?

Tags: drupal-7, blogs, categories

Is it possible to create categories or tags for the Drupal 7 Blog Module.

I have tried creating a new taxonomy, but can not select it as a new field for the content type. Is there an easier way?

Comment: You should be able to add it as a term reference.

Comment: It doesn't show up in the field to share drop down on the Blog Entry manage fields screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new field.  Make it type "Term Reference" and choose which taxonomy applies.  It's not a shared field.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 6 or 7, You can visit [here](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-7-taxonomy/) too